# Nginx how avoid location for subfolders?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I have several subfolders in a project in which of them I have a index.html files.

I prefer to call the index.html something like "gallery.html"

I tried

```
location gallery { 
index gallery.html; }
```

and it works, but is annoying use this directive for any subdfolder.

Is there a generic directive saying "whatever unique file_name.html found in a folder/subfolders call it?"

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `index` directive can take multiple parameters. You can add all the names for your index files, and Nginx will try each one until it finds a match. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index).

Comment: so location / { index index.html gallery.html library.html } ?

Comment: it doesn't change that much, if I have a new file, I should still re-open the conf, add the filename and restart nginx...I'd like, if possible, to avoid all these steps..

Answer (score 0):

If there's only a single html file in every subfolder, you should be able to tell NGINX to serve anything ending with `.html` with something like the following.

```
location gallery { 
    index .*\.html; }
```

Comment: I tried "location \ { 
    index .*\.html; }" but it doesn't work

Comment: Try using the try_files option instead.